# Apply distinct operator based on existing query

Tags: mongodb

I want to distinct the `name` on current query result, How could I do on MongoDB

Query syntax

```
db_conn.medical_records.find({"$or": [{"symptom_1": "nose allergic"},{"symptom_2": "nose allergic"}]})
```

Current query result, but not apply distinct on **name**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mary",    
    "symptom_1": null,
    "symptom_2": "nose allergic",
    "datetime": "2011-04-02"
},

{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jack",
    "symptom_1": "nose allergic",
    "symptoms_2": null,
    "datetime": "2011-04-02"
},

{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Mark",
    "symptoms_1": null,
    "symptoms_2": "nose allergic",
    "datetime": "2010-01-02"
},

{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Mark",
    "symptoms_1": "nose allergic",
    "symptoms_2": "headach",
    "datetime": "2015-04-04"
},
```

Apply distinct operator based on exsisting query

I want to distinct the `name` on current query result, How could I do on MongoDB

Query syntax

```
db_conn.medical_records.find({"$or": [{"symptom_1": "nose allergic"},{"symptom_2": "nose allergic"}]})
```

Current query result, but not apply distinct on **name**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mary",    
    "symptom_1": null,
    "symptom_2": "nose allergic",
    "datetime": "2011-04-02"
},

{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jack",
    "symptom_1": "nose allergic",
    "symptoms_2": null,
    "datetime": "2011-04-02"
},

{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Jack",
    "symptoms_1": null,
    "symptoms_2": "nose allergic",
    "datetime": "2010-01-02"
},

{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Mark",
    "symptoms_1": "nose allergic",
    "symptoms_2": "headach",
    "datetime": "2015-04-04"
}
```

Expected result

```
["Mary", "Jack", "Mark"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [**`collection.distinct`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

```js
db_conn.medical_records.distinct("name", 
    {
        "$or": [
                   { "symptom_1": <your symptom> },
                   { "symptom_2": <your symptom> }
               ]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first fix key names. Please fix if it is 'sympton_1' or 'symptons_1' and then apply mongo distinct on your collection. In distinct, you can specify criteria also.

```
db.collection.distinct({
    "$or": [
                { "symptom_1": "nose allergic" },
                { "symptom_2": "nose allergic" } // here you need to fix key name as it is 'symptoms_1' in some documents
            ]
 }
```

)